# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "Mpdf\Mpdf" not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\server\pdf.php:5

Tags: php, pdf, mpdf

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class "Mpdf\Mpdf" not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\server\pdf.php:5
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\server\pdf.php on line 5

*PHP 8.1.3, PHP Intelephense v1.8.2*

***compser.json***

```
{
"require": {
    "mpdf/mpdf": "^6.1"
      }
}
```

**composer.lock**

```
{
    "name": "mpdf/mpdf",
    "version": "v6.1.2",
    "source": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf.git",
    "reference": "da078bc2669d3f98553ac41f920ead4c17c951ad"
        },
```

**pdf.php**

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__ . '/pdf/autoload.php';

$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf;
$mpdf->WriteHTML('<h1>Hello world!</h1>');
$mpdf->Output();
```

***What I am doing wrong? What I am not understanding?***

***Thank you for your help!***

[image]

Comment: `require_once __DIR__ . '/pdf/autoload.php';`  - does that linked folder exist, and does it contain the `autoload.php` that Composer created? What did you try to resolve the problem?

Comment: Please keep in mind that mPDF v6.1.2 is **horribly** outdated. It was released in 2016, so it was nearly six years old when you posted this question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`require` path need update to :

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
```

Make sure that the library exists at `vendor` if not  run `composer update`

Answer (score 4):

In 6.1, there is no **\Mpdf\Mpdf** class, that is in v7+. So use here **new mPDF()**;

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/pdf/autoload.php';

$mpdf = new mPDF();
$mpdf->WriteHTML('<h1>Hello world!</h1>');
$mpdf->Output();
```

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this issue, removing mpdf folder and reinstall the last version using:
composer require mpdf/mpdf

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a CodeIgniter/Laravel framework, just update your `/App/Config/Constants.php` **COMPOSER_PATH** variable to point to your **right vendor folder** URL.

```
defined('COMPOSER_PATH') || define('COMPOSER_PATH', ROOTPATH . '../vendor/autoload.php');
```

I this case, I had moved my vendor folder out of the project folder.

This will make the class `\Mpdf\Mpdf()` available in all your Controllers and will reduce your `require_once ROOTPATH. '/../vendor/autoload.php';` clauses all over.

But if you are using it once in your project it will be okay to

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';
```

Make sure that you have installed Mpdf using composer

Answer (score -1):

laravel 10:
use "new \mPDF();" instead "new \Mpdf\Mpdf;"

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. Since mPDF v7 (released in 2017!), `Mpdf\Mpdf` is the full name of that class. How is the hint about Laravel related to the initial question?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

Laravel 8, got same error.

Just run the below in cmd then done.

```
composer require mpdf/mpdf
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. Why should that command resolve the problem?

Comment: Kindly provide more information to this answer. This will only work if composer had not installed mpdf. What if it was installed?